# .htaccess 301 redirect from one domain folder to another domain folder

Tags: .htaccess, dns, directory

I know I can use a .htaccess 301 to redirect from one domain-old/directory/ to a new domain-new/directory/, but my question is, I assume to I'd have to keep the old domain hosted to at least have the .htaccess file.

Both domains need to work. ie put in the old domain and it goes to the new.

So I could change the DNS IP address to point to a new server and have an alias there for the old domain but it'll bypass any .htaccess file on the old domain.

Is the only solution to go the .htaccess route and if so can I redirect the whole domain as well as a specific sub directory./

Comment: Why do you insist on a `.htaccess` style file "hosted" on the old domain? What you want (if I got you right) is that requests to the old domain are to be served by the new domain whilst the string domain visible in the browsers URL bar is changing to the new domain. For that it is sufficient to have both, old and new domain point to the same system by means of DNS. Next you need an alias for the domain name on that system, so that it reacts on requests to both domain names. And finally you use a `RewriteRule` in the host configuration to make any rewriting you want, internally or externally.

Comment: You do need to keep the old domain name registered though, otherwise you can not keep DNS entries alive.

Comment: Thanks arkascha. I've got what your saying. Both names will stay registered as the old one has been used for a long time, but the client wants to now use the new one. Some packaging is being printed this week with a QR that points to oldServer.com/directory/file.html. So we just need that QR to still work when we switch to newServer.com/directory/file.html in the next month or so and that's where I'll use the .htaccess to redirect as you say.

Comment: In general you should always prefer to place such commands in the real server configuration. `htaccess` style files are notoriously error prone, hard to debug and they _really_ slow the server down, often for nothing. They are only provided for situation where you do _not_ have access to the real host configuration, for example if you use a really cheap hosting provider.